# How to distinguish between Article Types with status=In development an status=Deployed via Apex

Tags: apex

I am developing a code which will list out all Knowledge Articles present in the Org.

To achieve it ,

- Step 1: I am retrieving all Object  first , using the   getGlobalDescribe() method .
- Step 2: I am filtering Objects that ends with __KAV.
- Step 3: I am using a SOSL Query to then retrieve Knowledge Articles belonging to each Article Type .

But if the Org has a Article Type with Status="In Developement" the SOSL fails with "The article type you are searching for has not been deployed " error.

So please help me to figure out a way of distinguishing between "Deployed" and "In developement" Article Types.

The SOSL query is

FIND 'test' RETURNING Solution (Id,SolutionName,LastModifiedDate,SolutionNote,CreatedById ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC), Case(Id,Subject,Description,LastModifiedDate,CreatedById ORDER BY LastModifiedDate DESC), 
New_Article_type__kav (Id,Title, Summary, LastPublishedDate, KnowledgeArticleId,CreatedById, UrlName, LastModifiedDate WHERE PublishStatus = 'Online' AND language = 'en_US' ORDER BY LastPublishedDate DESC), questionAndAnswer__kav (Id,Title, Summary, LastPublishedDate, KnowledgeArticleId,CreatedById, UrlName, LastModifiedDate WHERE PublishStatus = 'Online' AND language = 'en_US' ORDER BY LastPublishedDate DESC), New_1_Art_type__kav (Id,Title, Summary, LastPublishedDate, KnowledgeArticleId,CreatedById, UrlName, LastModifiedDate WHERE PublishStatus = 'Online' AND language = 'en_US' ORDER BY LastPublishedDate DESC) LIMIT 100

Thanks,
Pranjal Gawai

Comment: Can you share the SOSL query which gives an error ?

Comment: Hi Dave,I have edited my Question to include the Query